# What is the difference between ingress and reverse proxy

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I have used a few reverse proxies, such as HAProxy, Traefik and Kong. And when I started working with Kubernetes, I was confused by the concept of Ingress. Aren't the routings to back-end resources also achievable via reverse proxies? What is the purpose of using Ingress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any reverse proxy you want (for example [kube-nginx-proxy](https://github.com/kylemcc/kube-nginx-proxy)).

In this case you need to perform some configuration steps, which could take a lot of time.

**Ingress** is specially designed for fast setup. The only thing you should do is to describe your configuration using yaml, which is easier and faster than third-party solutions.

Also you can use, for example, [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes) for this purpose, in which case Ingress is already integrated.